# Where to hire CiviCRM consultants or developers

Tags: developer

Is there a directory of CiviCRM companies or freelancers to make CiviCRM features that we need?

Comment: Thanks, Fabian, for responding. Yes, we tried that weeks ago. Three of three email queries with companies from that page/list have gotten us no response of any kind. They seem to all be companies for hosting/developing, long-term, with service contracts etc—not freelance/troubleshooting/fixes services.
We are disappointed that our post HERE on SE forum (http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8597/contribution-form-fails-bounces-to-home-page-or-timeout-error), posted on Jan 1, got no responses. Our seemingly endless investigation of this has yielded tons of minutiae, but no fix or smoking g

Comment: Hi Greg, sorry to hear that. I am not sure why this happened maybe just bad luck... If you still have not found anyone, feel free to contact us (if it is ok for you that our company is located in Germany): www.systopia.de - I will also answer to your other question.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to have a look at CiviCRM's [Partners and contributors page.](https://civicrm.org/providers)
For special requirements, it would be helpful if you specify a bit more in detail, what you are looking for. Also, this CiviCRM forum may be of interest: [Professional CiviCRM Services](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?board=19.0)

Regards
Fabian