# I want to hire a CiviCRM (Joomla) expert to fix a problem

Tags: civicontribute, error

I have an immediate need ([Contribution Form fails; bounces to Home Page or timeout error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8597/contribution-form-fails-bounces-to-home-page-or-timeout-error)) and ongoing needs as well, for multiple client sites. This is urgent. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The best source for finding partners is https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

There you can search on country and the services they provide.